# Activiti + Spring Boot + Gradle build hangs while gradle clean test

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot, activiti

I am having an issue with executing gradle clean test command.
My application is using activiti for workflow.
Git url: https://github.com/sanelib/eBOSS/tree/merge-before-dev
Branch: "merge-before-dev" is having more tests for activiti worflow process. But it execute only 6 of 12 integration tests from "core" module. If I use @Ignore to any random 6 tests then it success for rest 6. I have put some console out to debug and found it hangs on starting activiti process.

This source has also included database schema in /scripts folder. Let me know if you miss any required file for testing in your environment.

Can anybody look into this and give me solution?

Comment: If is use maxParallelForks = Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors() / 2 then it works. Do not understand why it happen for small tests.

Comment: Also if I put forkEvery = 10 with maxParallelForks = 1. It works. But due to this it restart after every 10 tests and cause longer time to execute.

Comment: I've pulled the project switched to `merge-before-dev`, run `gradle clean test` from command line and some tests finished with exceptions. Is that ok?

Comment: Are you satisfied with your findings or do you need further investagation? Checkout and build results `23 tests completed, 14 failed
:core:test FAILED`

Answer (score 1):

I got also result: `23 tests completed, 14 failed :core:test FAILED`

Than I randomly picked one of your tests and it failed in isolation also. It doesn't seem to be concurrency problem.

Root cause seem to be this:

```
2016-02-05 20:56:16.556  WARN 16072 --- [           main] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
```

[Place break-point on this line in Hibernate](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/972a4f79b6040fa76a463f5e1bedd5b07ecee45f/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/engine/jdbc/internal/JdbcServicesImpl.java#L205).

So it does seem to be connection problem.